# Is it possible to re-install Flash ActiveX in 2021?

Tags: internet-explorer, flash, flash-player, activex

I still use Adobe Flash Player daily. I know it is no longer supported, I don't need to hear a rant about how unsafe it is in the replies. Recently, my computer updated to [version KB4577586](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4577586-update-for-the-removal-of-adobe-flash-player-october-27-2020-931521b9-075a-ce54-b9af-ff3d5da047d5) automatically. This version removes the in-built ActiveX Flash Player from Windows, and when I went to start up Trillix Flash Decompiler I get this issue:

'Unfortunately, Adobe Flash Player ActiveX isn't installed in your computer. Flash Decompiler requires this ActiveX control for proper working. Please visit [www.adobe.com](http://www.adobe.com) and install Flash Player or contact Eltima technical support.'

When I try to reinstall ActiveX from the installers on archive.org [here](https://archive.org/download/flashplayerarchive/pub/flashplayer/installers/archive/) it says 'Your Microsoft Internet Explorer browser includes the latest version of the Adobe Flash Player built-in. Windows Update will inform you when new versions of the Flash Player are available.'

I have opened Internet Explorer and tried to view Flash Content, and it is definitely not re-installed.

Is there any way I can re-install the ActiveX version of Adobe Flash Player in 2021?

Note: My earliest system restore point is **after** the update was applied, and I don't really want to use a virtual machine every time or re-install Windows.

Comment: @Tetsujin Nope, every answer here seems to either be for the Flash versions you can just install with the installers in the archive.org page seen above, or for versions still outstanding on your computer, none of them seem to be able to re-install the ActiveX version (the one I specifically want) once the Windows update KB4577586 has removed it.

Comment: I could get a Windows 7 Virtual Machine I believe, but that is a lot of hassle to boot up a virtual machine every time I want to decompile an SWF.

Comment: The KB you linked says to do a system restore, or reinstall.

Comment: @Tetsujin I probably should have mentioned it in the post, but my earliest system restore point is after the update was applied.

Comment: Realistically you can’t.  Adobe removed all earlier versions of Adobe Flash from their website.  Adobe added a kill switch any version that is available to download.  Additionally, all versions of Windows that are supported, have disabled Adobe Flash.  All future builds of Windows 10, Adobe Flash will be disabled, basically the duplicate present the only methods that exist.  Even if you had NOT installed that update the next cumulative update would have disabled Adobe Flash.  If you had delayed that update the one after that would have disabled it.  21H1 will have it already disabled

Comment: You disliked my answer because the alternative software I proposed was too old, but you forgot perhaps that SWF is an old format that is on the way out. Anyway, I deleted my answer.

Comment: If you're going to continue to use structures with no more support & no more maintenance… & in this case active kill-switches, then you should consider a Win7 VM, not connected to the internet, where you can sandbox all this old stuff as long as you like. Your chances of keeping it going in Win10 are very slim. For now, Edge on Win10 can run ActiveX controls etc in an IE11 tab, but that will not last forever. IE11 itself is also dead.